# why am I getting TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str' on Django Deserialization?

Tags: python, django, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying out using AJAX to implement tags for Book Blog posts. I want to use TDD to check and make sure that they filter properly but am running into issues. Mainly when I try and Deserialize the JSONResponse content, it throws an error when I try and iter through it.

error message:

```
  File "E:\04_projects\01_Python\10_book_blog\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 70, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(objects, **options)
  File "E:\04_projects\01_Python\10_book_blog\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 111, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
                       ~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\04_projects\01_Python\10_book_blog\posts\tests\test_views.py", line 103, in test_returns_filtered_posts
    for obj in decereal:
  File "E:\04_projects\01_Python\10_book_blog\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 74, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError
```

test case that makes the error:

```
def test_returns_filtered_posts(self):
        # makes one post with a tag and one post without
        t1 = Tag.objects.create(tag_name='test', group_name='general')
        p1 = Post.objects.create(book_title='test_book')
        p2 = Post.objects.create(book_title='test_book2')
        p1.tags.add(t1)

        # simulates clicking the 'test' tag
        response = self.client.post(reverse('ajax_post'), {'tag[]': ['test', 'general']})
        # decerealizes the data
        decereal = deserialize('json', response.content)
        # print for debugging
        for obj in decereal:
            print(obj)
        # bad test case but not getting this far
        self.assertNotIn(p2, decereal)
```

The view that is called:

```
def ajax_call(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Post.objects.all())
    # this was just for testing
    uncereal = serializers.deserialize('json', data)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

I can iter through `uncereal` in `ajax_call` without issue, the problem comes in my test case when I try it the same way that they do in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data, I get an error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think the basic problem is that [`JsonResponse` expects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) to receive a dict instance, but you are passing it a string of serialized json. With `safe=False` this will give you a string double-encoded into a JSON string.  Then when you come to deserialize the response it's trying to inflate that back into model instances e.g. expects `d` to be a dict but it's just a string.

Comment: ok that makes sense! I'll look into passing query objects through JSONResponses and get back to the post if it works.

Comment: you might be better off just using `HttpResponse` instead of `JsonResponse`... I think `JsonResponse` does not handle serializing querysets, which is what `serializers.serialize` does for you.  The result of `serializers.serialize` is just a string you can return from `HttpResponse`, you don't need `JsonResponse` if you already serialized it to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested fix:

```py
def ajax_call(request):
    serialized = serializers.serialize('json', Post.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(serialized)
```

Explanation expanded from my comments:

I think the basic problem is that `JsonResponse` expects to receive a dict instance, but you are passing it a *string* of already serialized json. With `safe=False` it will accept other JSON-serializable types besides dict (e.g. list, string, number, None).

So if you pass a string to `serialize` it will escape it and wrap in double quotes to make it a JSON string.  So you have ended up with a JSON string of a JSON value serialized to string.

Then when you come to deserialize the response it's trying to inflate that back into model instances e.g. expects `d` to be a dict but it's just a string.

So the simplest fix is just to stop double-encoding things in your view function.

You want to use `serializers.serialize` rather than `JsonResponse` to do the serialization, because the former understands how to serialize model instances. Having serialized to a string of JSON you can then return that string with an ordinary `HttpResponse`.

Comment: I'll try this, I agree that double serializing seems pointless and I'd like to cut out the redundency

Comment: Ok that worked and worked better, thank you for the help, changing my response on what worked to your fix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the way you're trying to deserialize the JSON response in your test case. The deserialize() function expects a file-like object or a string containing the serialized data, but you're passing the JSON response content directly, which leads to the error.

To fix this, you should use the json.loads() method to convert the JSON response content to a Python data structure before deserializing it

```
# Convert the JSON response content to a Python data structure
data = json.loads(response.content)

# Deserialize the data
decereal = list(serializers.deserialize('json', data))
```

Comment: You got it it 100%, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: surely this is wrong? there's no point calling `deserialize` is you already deserialized it with `json.loads`. https://github.com/django/django/blob/68912e4f6f84f21322f92a2c7b6c77f68f91b9c9/django/core/serializers/__init__.py#L138 the method takes a string arg. If this works in your case it's because you messed up by double-serializing your value in the view code... but double-deserializing the result of that seems like the wrong fix

Comment: _"The deserialize() function expects a file-like object or a string containing the serialized data, but you're passing the JSON response content directly"_ this is wrong, the `response.content` is a string so it should be the right thing to pass to `deserialize`.  The problem is that, due to the double-serialization in the view, `deserialize` can't inflate the value back into a model instance, because you made a string-in-a-string instead.